# Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string, publish

I am trying to publish my mvc 3 project but i can`t connect to the sql server(using EF), because of the wrong connection string. Here it is:

```
  <add name="PackStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PackStore.csdl|res://*/Models.PackStore.ssdl|res://*/Models.PackStore.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;workstation id=PackStore.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=*****;pwd=****;data source=PackStore.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=PackStore&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I took this part form the my hoster:

```
workstation id=PackStore.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=*****;pwd=****;data source=PackStore.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=PackStore
```

Mvc project works well on the local server, but when publishing i get "Keyword not supported: 'metadata' " . Where is my mistake? Thnaks for the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one...

```
<add name="PackStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=PackStore.mssql.somee.com;Initial Catalog=PackStore;User ID=***;Password=****;'"  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Edit..

```
<add name="PackStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='workstation id=PackStore.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=*****;pwd=****;data source=PackStore.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=PackStore;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: You are talking about replacing quot... i`v already tried this. It did`nt work, instead of "keyword not supported" i get:              `"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"`

Comment: Try to check your connection because the meta data problem will be resolved with this connection string. Check instance name or userid and pass.

Comment: the userid and pass are correct 100%, and what about instance name? You are talking about connection name?

Comment: you can observe that error... the metadata issue has been resolved with that

Comment: excuse me, maybe i am dummy, but i don`t get how the metadata issue could be resolved, if i still have "keyword not supported: 'metadata'" error.....(

Comment: and in addition on the local server everything is ok, so it is quiet strange.....

Comment: the most funny was that it WAS working the first time, when i published my project. But then i decided to change some in the project and after it refresh all files. And here am i.. Ok.. thanks for your answer, i`l try to make something with this)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while converting from Linq To Sql to Entity framework as well, even after fixing my connection strings. It turned out some asp:SqlDataSource controls needed to be switched to asp:EntityDataSource.

Before:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceProducts" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT Id, Description FROM [Product]"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:crmConnectionString %>" CacheDuration="5" CacheExpirationPolicy="Absolute">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

After:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceProducts" runat="server" Select="Id, Description"
        EntitySetName="Products" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:crmConnectionString %>" DefaultContainerName="CRM" >
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: Handy to note that if you don't want to use an EDMX and want to use SQL, the prvider name needs to change like this: providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config you need to have two separate connections:  One is for the Entity Frame work and one is for ADO.net

Should look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="LoginDB" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=int422_113b16;User ID=****;Password=****" />
        <add name="BlogEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/App_Code.BlogModel.csdl|res://*/App_Code.BlogModel.ssdl|res://*/App_Code.BlogModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source****;initial catalog=int422_113b16;user id=****;password=****;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove he meta data from your connection string. That is only for the local debugging. For the online application can does not require that.

Kindly try the connection string given by naim

Comment: I`v tried this, asme prob. But if`l remove  `metadata=res://*;` form my connection string, i`l get the following error: `Some required information is missing from the connection string. The 'metadata' keyword is always required.`

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, seems like the connection string from the somee server has to be between two `&quot;`
That's all I changed and it works...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why people think that you need two connections in your web.config, that's not true.  First thing I like to check is to see if my connection works in Visual Studio.  Try going to your server explorer and connect to your database there. If you are able to connect with no problem and you are able to see your tables then you know its not a connection problem.  Second thing make sure that your Model name matches the name in your web.config.  This minimizes the amount of confusion in your project and finally make sure that your model name space points to your projects namespace, this way you can just call on your model by its name and not have to import or fully qualify it.

You should be able to create a strong view using any of the tables in your model.  That's what I did for mine, I didn't modify the connection string like many suggest, or removed the metadata.

Check this [troubleshooting](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/) guide it might shine some light, and help you understand how the entity connection works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception, but was able to fix it by keeping the `ConnectionString` the same but using an `EntityConnection` instead of a `SqlConnection`.